# How to move objects with the mouse cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Found a script that implements this, but if you move the cursor too fast, then the object is behind.
I tried many ways and even limit fps.
In Unity itself, there are not too many lags, but when I launch on the phone through Unity Remote there are strong remaining. Maybe this is not the most powerful phone? But the rest of the objects move normally

```
private Vector3 offset;
```

We move if the mouse is pressed

```
void OnMouseDown()
{

    offset = gameObject.transform.position -
    Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x+ RotationCar, 
                                                Input.mousePosition.y + RotationCar, 50));

}
```

Save coordinates if mouse is pressed

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{

    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 50);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPosition) + offset;
}
```

Comment: launching through unity remote will incur a substantial debugger communication overhead. detach and run regularly, it should not be as severe in a release build.
also consider hiding the cursor while dragging.

Comment: unlike its name `onMouseDrag` is not the perfect solution for dragging objects around. it can tell you when your mouse is dragging over an object. If you want to implement drag and drop [follow this tutorial](http://unity.grogansoft.com/drag-and-drop/)

Comment: Not the main cause of the problem but `Camera.main`  is an expensive operation because it calls `FindGameObjectsWithTag` internally and [doesn't cache the result](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html). You should cache the result yourself, e.g. with `private Camera myMain;` ... `void Start(){... myMain = Camera.main; ...}` then `myMain.ScreenToWorldPoint(...)`

Comment: Well in general Unity Remote is for debugging .. you can never expect a good performance from it. How is it behaving after deploying?

Comment: Note the lag is a side issue issue here -- you should always code in a way that would cope with any theoretical lag (in this case, prepare for the finger to have moved outside the object from one frame to another even when still touching). Bizhan's comment contains a drag & drop tutorial link.